# Could not cast value of type '__NSSingleObjectArrayI' to 'NSDictionary' in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary

When I parse the Api I got response and stored full response to Dictionary then I split it to array and dictionary, But I get error so please help to solve the error,

Here I give the code what I am tried.

```
let responseDictionary:NSDictionary = responseObject as! NSDictionary
        print(responseDictionary)
        if let statusCode:NSNumber = responseDictionary.value(forKey: "success") as? NSNumber{
            if statusCode == 1{
                print("statusCode :",statusCode)

                let incomingRequetArray:NSArray = responseDictionary.value(forKey: "incoming_requests") as! NSArray
                print("incomingRequetArray",incomingRequetArray)

                if (incomingRequetArray.count > 0)
                {
                    let requestDataDict:NSDictionary = incomingRequetArray.value(forKey: "request_data") as! NSDictionary  -----> Error in this line
                    print("requestDataDict",requestDataDict)

                    let ownerArray:NSArray = requestDataDict.value(forKey: "owner") as! NSArray
                    print("ownerArray",ownerArray)
                    self.mutDictOwner = ownerArray.object(at: 0) as! NSMutableDictionary

                }
            }
```

responseDictionary is

```
"incoming_requests" =     (
            {
        datetime = "2017-04-17 12:25:58";
        later = 0;
        "request_data" =             {
            dog =                 (
            );
            owner =                 {
                address = "";
                "d_latitude" = "0.00000000";
                "d_longitude" = "0.00000000";
                "dest_latitude" = "0.00000000";
                "dest_longitude" = "0.00000000";
                latitude = "11.01449160";
                longitude = "76.98273220";
                name = "Sss Sas";
                "num_rating" = 0;
                "payment_type" = 1;
                phone = "+919123456789";
                picture = "";
                rating = "0.00";
            };
            "payment_mode" = 1;
        };
        "request_id" = 1474;
        "request_services" = 30;
        "time_left_to_respond" = 21;
    }
);
"is_approved" = 1;
"is_approved_txt" = Approved;
"is_available" = 1;
success = 1;
```

Comment: **Don't** use `valueForKey` (in the broadest sense that causes the error), use key subscripting. **Don't** use `NSArray / NSDictionary`, use Swift native collection types. **Don't** use `NSMutable...` collection types in Swift at all. **Don't** annotate types the compiler can infer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your are doing wrong incomingRequetArray is NSArray and you are getting value for key

Write this

```
let requestDataDict:NSDictionary = incomingRequetArray[0]as!NSDictionary
let newDict: NSDictionary = requestDataDict.object(forKey: "request_data")
print("newDict is ---%@", newDict)
```

**you have used NSDictionary and NSArray format So I have written the code according to yours. But for further uses in swift Do not use NSDictionary and NSArray.**

Answer (score 3):

It is because your "request_data" is an Object and not a Dictionary, see how "incoming_request" has started (with a " (  ") and "request_data" is starting with "{". what you can do to access is this

```
let requestDataDict:NSDictionary = incomingRequetArray.value(forKey: "request_data") as! [AnyObject]-----> Error in this line
                print("requestDataDict",requestDataDict)
                let x = requestDataDict[0] as! NSDictionary
                let ownerArray:NSArray = x.value(forKey: "owner")as! NSArray
```

Comment: Thanks it is helpful for me.

Comment: And i totally agree with @Lalit jee on this that you should not use NSDictionary and NSArray

Answer (score 2):

This is a reasonable Swift *transcription* which solves the error. It uses a type alias for convenience.

```
typealias JSONDictionary = [String:Any]

let responseDictionary = responseObject as! JSONDictionary
print(responseDictionary)
if let success = responseDictionary["success"] as? Int, success == 1 {
    print("statusCode :", success)

    let incomingRequestArray = responseDictionary["incoming_requests" as! [JSONDictionary]
    print("incomingRequetArray",incomingRequestArray)

    if let requestDataDict = incomingRequestArray.first {
        print("requestDataDict",requestDataDict)

        if let ownerArray = requestDataDict["owner"] as? [JSONDictionary], !ownerArray.isEmpty {
        print("ownerArray",ownerArray)
        self.mutDictOwner = ownerArray[0] as! JSONDictionary
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the line that's throwing an error try to change `incomingRequetArray.value...` to `incomingRequetArray[0].value...` as you need to access the internal dictionary that's contained in an array and then query for the value for given key.

Comment: Thanks it is helpful for me.